# Interpreting ANOVA results in the educational context

Tags: anova, experiment-design, application

I have run an experiment in a six-week course to measure the effect of my educational treatment on student engagement.  The treatment happens on weeks 4 and 6 of the course (for all of the students) and week 5 is meant to be the control (for all of the students). The line chart with error bar is as follows:
[image]
And here is the boxplot:
[image]
I have run an ANOVA and the results turned out to be this:

```
data:  count and as.factor(week)
F = 5.7806, num df = 2.00, denom df = 129.44, p-value = 0.003939
```

Which means that at least two of the weeks have different engagement levels.
I have also done a post-hoc analysis which revealed that the engagement in weeks 5 and 6 are significantly different.

Tukey Test

```
Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = count ~ as.factor(week), data = .)

$`as.factor(week)`
                   diff        lwr      upr     p adj
week 4-week 5  9.334825 -5.8595239 24.52917 0.3171024
week 6-week 5 24.000000  8.7502979 39.24970 0.0007633
week 6-week 4 14.665175 -0.5291744 29.85952 0.0610931
```

and Bonferroni Test

```
       week 4  week 5 
week 5 0.44534 -      
week 6 0.07116 0.00079

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

My question is: How can I make sure that the higher engagement in week 6 is due to my treatment rather than a natural increase in engagement in the last week of the course?

Comment: From what you say here, I see no way to answer your final question. Note 'almost' signif diff btw wks 4 & 6. Did you expect weeks 4 & 6 > wk 5? In what sense is wk 5 a 'control'? // Data for wk 6 especially may not be normal, Maybe outliers driving up variance and masking some differences. Maybe try Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric ANOVA with Bonferroni-level 2-sample Wilcoxon tests for ad hoc analysis. Sort of doubt you'll find anything more than here, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @BruceET About the treatment, I sent students feedback emails in weeks 4, 5 and 6. In weeks 4 and 6, I changed a certain feature of the email to test if it increases student engagement. My expected result was weeks 4 & 6 > week 5.